# How to start a Trace Session (similar to TraceView) from a .pdb file in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, trace

I've created a VB.net application that uses a specific print driver our company has developed.  I have the .pdb files for the driver and can use TraceView.exe to start trace sessions and get debug info which is very helpful for our driver team when I find issues.  I'd like to be able to start a log session from the pdb files and display events as they occur (similar to TraceView) from within my application (have a button in my app to start Tracing) to simplify debugging for other users in our company.  Is this possible with .NET?

I've been reading the System.Diagnostics.Eventing / .Tracing / etc documentation but have not been able to piece all this together as most of the documentation seems to be about providing trace logs, not starting and consuming them.

*Note, my application can already detect the driver version installed and navigate to the correct pdb files on the network.  I just need to find a way to read them in and start a logging session for each provider with the correct levels and flags and then capture the events from a listener or something.

Comment: Is TraceView based on ETW? Most of the framework EventSource related classes are designed for ETW providers. I believe you'll want to look at the [TraceEvent nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent/) package which lets you control/consume traces, but I don't know how that interacts with PDBs at all. Vance Morrison has a number of blog posts and examples on using it. The source code for TraceEvent is included in the [PerfView github repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview), so that might give you an idea of how to use it with PDBs.

Comment: Yes, TraceView is a tool based on ETW.  I'll give that a look and see what I come up with.  Thank you.